# Type hints for decorator to make argument optional

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-typing

I have a number of methods that take a "connection pool", which can be created once and reused throughout the code base. However, in some cases I am fine with creating a new  connection pool on-the-fly (such as for short-lived programs).

For the purpose of this example, let's call this `ConnPool`. My methods may look something like this:

```py
from typing import List

async def list_jobs(namespaces: List[str], *, pool: ConnPool) -> List[str]:
   ...
```

I would like to create a *correctly typed* decorator for these methods that turn the pool argument into an optional `pool: Optional[ConnPool] = None`. If given, use it, if not given create a new pool on-the-fly:

```py
def handle_pool(f):
  async def wrapper(*args, pool: Optional[ConnPool] = None, **kwargs):
    if pool:
      return await f(*args, pool=pool, **kwargs)
    else:
      return await f(*args, pool=ConnPool(), **kwargs)
```

The hard part is not the implementation, but getting the type hints correct. I tried a solution with `ParamSpec`, but it does not handle additional keyword arguments correctly.

```py
# No errors from mypy or pylance
from typing import Awaitable, Callable, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar

from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R", covariant=True)


class ConnPool:
    pass


class OptionalPool(Protocol[P, R]):
    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, pool: Optional[ConnPool] = None, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        ...


def make_optional(f: Callable[Concatenate[ConnPool, P], Awaitable[R]]) -> OptionalPool[P, Awaitable[R]]:
    async def wrapper(*args: P.args, pool: Optional[ConnPool] = None, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        if pool:
            return await f(pool, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return await f(ConnPool(), *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@make_optional
async def test_function(pool: ConnPool, first: str) -> int:
    print(f"first: {first}, pool: {repr(pool)}")
    return 2


async def main() -> None:
    # Type of "test_function" is "OptionalPool[(first: str), Awaitable[int]]"
    # Argument hinting (VS Code) shows "test_function(*args: P.args, pool: Optional[ConnPool] = None, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Awaitable[int]"
    test = await test_function("first")
    print(f"Returned {test}")
    return None
```

It clearly detects the arguments I want, but it does not nicely unpack the arguments and keyword arguments. I know this is [specifically called out as not supported](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#concatenating-keyword-parameters), so I wonder what other options I have (if any).

TL;DR: How do you implement a properly typed decorator to turn a known (hardcoded keyword) argument from required to optional with a default value of `None`, while retaining all other args + kwargs and still get a nice function signature?